# ¿Existe la palabra "censurólogo"?

Tags: gramática, significado, palabras-raras, dle

Recientemente vi a una persona usar la palabra "censurólogo" que personalmente creí que no existía, pero la tipeo en el traductor de Google y la traduce como "censorship". ¿Es una palabra en español válida o simplemente es un error del traductor de Google?

Comment: ¿Qué es un "censurólogo"?

Comment: Esta sería una pregunta en la que conviene añadir el contexto y explicar con qué sentido se estaba usando la palabra. El sufijo "-ologo" es una variante del sufijo "-logo" que indica "estudioso o especialista en una materia o ciencia". No me parecería imposible que alguien fuese un estudioso de las censuras (aunque sería una profesión muy especializada). Una cosa es que no aparezca en el diccionario (como lo hacen epidemiólogo, musicólogo...) y otra es que como palabra esté mal formada. Otra es que designe a una "profesión/ciencia" real. Un historiador, sería quien estudiaría sobre censuras.

Comment: @Diego Tu frase "como lo hacen epidemiólogo, musicólogo" es digna de una nueva pregunta. Si no te molesta, puedo tomarla.

Comment: En el contexto en que se usó, se uso en reemplazo de censor. Pero esto es parte de la anécdota porque Google la traduce sin contexto. Si el significado de censor es incorrecto, pero tiene otro significado igual quisiera saberlo.

Comment: @Gustavson esas dos **sí** aparecen. Tal vez debí haber sido más claro y decir "como *sí* lo hacen por ejemplo "epidemiólogo", "musicólogo", ...)", pero como hay límite de caracteres a veces ando quitando palabrejas por aquí y allá. Si ves una pregunta (debido a esos términos o de gramática o lo que sea) siéntete libre de formularla.

Comment: Pablo, supongo que al añadirle el sufijo "-ologo" estás cambiando el sentido de caulquier palabra de "el que hace X" a "El que estudia x". "Músico vs. musicólogo" sería el ejemplo más claro del cambio de significado de "censor vs. censurologo".

Comment: @Diego Me refiero al uso de "hacer" en español como se usa la proforma "do" en inglés.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La palabra **sí** aparece en el DLE. No completa, pero es una palabra bien formada mediante el uso del sufijo [*-logo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NZTxcTa), que aparece en el diccionario:

> ‒́logo, ga
>
> Del lat. -lŏgus, y este del gr. -λόγος -lógos.
>
> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'persona versada' o 'especialista' en lo que el primer elemento indica. *Zoólogo*, *psicólogo*.

Por tanto, según el diccionario, un *censurólogo* es una persona versada o especialista en la censura.

Los sufijos productivos, como -logo, nos permiten crear nuevas palabras bien formadas que son inmediatamente válidas, aunque no tengan entrada propia en el diccionario.

Comment: ¿Realmente son automáticamente validadas? ¿No hay ningún límite? O sea, ¿yo podría inventarme la palabra _tejadólogo_  (persona especialista o muy versada en tejados) y sería válida? Que conste que esto no es una pregunta irónica, es una solicitud real de información xD

Comment: @Alicia buena pregunta. ¿Podríamos afirmar que son válidas todas aquellas construcciones a partir de un elemento compositivo que también aparece en el DLE? Por ejemplo _[psico-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UW2IrlV)_.

Comment: @Alicia Normalmente usamos raíces con la misma procedencia que el elemento compositivo, así que tal vez la forma preferible de *tejadólogo* sería ligeramente distinta (*censura* en latín es también *censura*). Pero sí, la palabra es válida. Eso no quiere decir que su significado no sea absurdo. El lenguaje es neutral y nos permite usarlo para decir estupideces.

Comment: @fedorqui El problema es que el significado de *psico-* es bastante limitado. Pero, si la palabra resultante tiene sentido, adelante. De hecho, no es tan raro ver nuevas palabras formadas con él (ahora se me ocurre *psicodrama*).

Comment: @Gorpik - ¡No me gustaría jugar Scrabble contigo!